# Computing the homology of $\mathbb{S}^1$ attached with two $2$-cells via degree $2$ and $3$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This exercise is inspired from an exercise found in Hatcher's book, p. 156, 13:

> Compute the homology of the space $X$ obtained from the $1$-sphere
>   $\mathbb{S}^1$ by attaching two $2$-cells via attaching maps
>   $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ of degree $2$ and $3$.

My result is:
$$\begin{align*}H_k(X) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & k = 0,\\
\mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z} \oplus 3\mathbb{Z}) & k = 1,\\
0 & k >1
\end{cases}\end{align*}$$

is this correct?

**Edit.** Giving it a second look, writing $\mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z} \oplus 3\mathbb{Z})$ is blatantly stupid. Now I understand the "matrix notation" provided in the answer and can apply it to the cellular chain complex of the space $X$:
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
If we write $s$ for the $2$-cell with degree $2$ and $t$ for the $2$-cell with degree $3$, the *cellular boundary formula* yields $$\partial s = 2a \qquad \text{and} \qquad \partial t = 3 a$$ where $a$ denotes the $1$-cell of the cell-complex.

Comment: $2\Bbb Z\oplus 3\Bbb Z$ is not a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown well...I posted my idea too early..

Comment: It is not that your idea was posted too early: is that what you wrote does not make sense (My guess is, you wanted to write something like $Z/(2Z+3Z)$, with a sum and not a direct sum)

Comment: And, by the way, you did not post any idea. You just wrote down the result.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez with idea I meant solution...sorry.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Edited the post to add my "idea".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cellular chain group is given by $C_2=\Bbb Z^2$, $C_1=\Bbb Z$ and $C_0=\Bbb Z$. The map from $C_2$ to $C_1$ is given by the matrix $(2\ 3)$
and that from $C_1$ to $C_0$ is zero. The $C_2\to C_1$ map is surjective, but has kernel $\cong \Bbb Z$, so $H_2(X)\cong \Bbb Z$ while $H_1(X)=0$.

Comment: Could you let me know why the map $C_2\rightarrow C_1$ is surjective?

Comment: $-(2)+3=1$ @LevBan